# SQL - Retrieve rows by indexed column - performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have this table, with a index for payment_id (not shown):

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.payments
(
 payment_id bigint NOT NULL,
 box_id bigint ,
 mov_id bigint ,
 code_co character varying(5) NOT NULL,
 client_id bigint NOT NULL,
 user_created character varying(15) NOT NULL,
 date_payment timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
)
;
```

This table has near 30 million records

I have a test table like this

```
insert into dummy_table (payment_id) values (294343, 5456565);
```

A explain analyze of this query retrieves a result in about 4 minutes:

```
select * from myschema.payments where payment_id in (select payment_id from dummy_table )
```

However, if I perform something like this:

```
select * from myschema.payments where 
payment_id in (294343, 5456565);
```

I get the result in ms.

Those payment_id values are variable, how can I improve the performance with a variable amount of different payment_id by every execution? if helpful, my 'in' statement will have about 20 payment_id each time.

This is the explain analyze of the query select * from myschema.payments where payment_id in (select payment_id from dummy_table )

```
"Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=100.00..6877.47 rows=137 width=274) (actual      time=47229.725..215893.809 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  Join Filter: (payments.payment_id = dummy_table.payment_id)"
"  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 47939387"
"  ->  Foreign Scan on payments  (cost=100.00..118.22 rows=274 width=274)      (actual time=1.334..198599.055 rows=23969695 loops=1)"
"  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..6751.03 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=2 loops=23969695)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on dummy_table  (cost=0.00..6751.02 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.009..6.236 rows=2 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 0.238 ms"
"Execution time: 215894.462 ms"
```

EDIT: added the explain analyze for a join version:

```
select p.*
from myschema.payments p join
 dummy_table t
 on p.payment_id = t.payment_id;

"Nested Loop  (cost=100.00..6877.47 rows=3 width=274) (actual time=50680.577..228816.409 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  Join Filter: (payments.payment_id = dummy_table.payment_id)"
"  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 47939388"
"  ->  Foreign Scan on payments p  (cost=100.00..118.22 rows=274 width=274) (actual time=1.261..211380.739 rows=23969695 loops=1)"
"  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..6751.03 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=2 loops=23969695)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on dummy_table t  (cost=0.00..6751.02 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.022..9.566 rows=2 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 0.311 ms"
"Execution time: 228817.094 ms"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `join`:

```
select p.*
from myschema.payments p join
     dummy_table t
     on p.payment_id = t.payment_id;
```

Try this version . . . which is a bit more brute force:

```
select p.*
from dummy_table t left join
     myschema.payments p
     on p.payment_id = t.payment_id;
```

Comment: Added the explain analyze of this query in the post.

Comment: @NatyBizz . . . That is odd.  Any sane optimizer should say "dummy_table" has two rows and there is an appropriate index for the `join`.  I wonder if Postgres gets confused because no columns from `dummy_table` are being selected.